# AWS sdk version 2, create ec2 instance

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I might have missed it, but i cant figure out how to create ec2 instance in ruby via the version 2 of the aws sdk.. anyone?

cant find any solution in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab a client with

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(
  region: region_name,
  credentials: credentials
)
```

, then launch instances with `ec2.run_instances`.See documentation below.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#run_instances-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

There are sdk gems for rby. To install the sdk-2 gem you need to add

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'`
```

In your Gemfile and install it with `bundle install` command. After that you can refer this docs for the rest: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html

And examples right there:

```
# resource constructors
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2', credentials: credentials)

# client constructors
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region:'us-west-2', credentials: credentials)
```

The configuration examples are there as well.